# How to extract information from a shapefile with the command ogrinfo in a machine readable way

Tags: gdal, shapefile, epsg, srid, ogrinfo

I am looking for information like the SRID/CRS for a shapefile in an automated way.

I know that by using `ogrinfo path/to/xxx-filename.shp yyy-layer -so` I can see some output with indentation left to square brackets `[ ... ]`.

Is there a way to extract the SRID in an automatic way? I know the bit of information that I need should be `ID["EPSG",4326]`, however it looks like that output could have different structures e.g. apparently sometimes I should see `AUTHORITY`  instead, but I am not sure why.

For example, I think that given that the output for my particular shape file contains `BASEGEOGCRS` it seems it could be considered WKT2 and for some reason the output structure could be different than the one in WKT.

I am not too familiar with the geographical/GIS terminology and context, so I might be not so precise with the request above.

So far I came up with this pile of convoluted commands which does not look enough robust to me as I am relying on spaces indentation and parsing the EPSG digits:

```
SHP_SRID=$(ogrinfo path/to/xxx-filename.shp yyy-layer -so | grep '^\s\s\s\sID\["EPSG"' | grep -oP '\d+')
```

Is there a better way, perhaps involving JSON/XML parsing e.g. by piping into the `jq` command?

Comment: I think the right answer to this question is going to depend on what you want to do with that information once you get it. Its possible for different WKT strings to refer to identical coordinate systems, and sometimes they have identifiers (like EPSG codes) and sometimes they don't, sometimes they can be recognised as EPSG codes, sometimes not.

Comment: As I said I am lacking field knowledge with geo/GIS stuff. I assume that given a ESRI shapefile, then I can always extract metadata from it and that some of this metadata is expected to always be there e.g. the SRID which I assume should always be there. In this specific scenario I need the SRID to then be able to invoke the command shp2pgsql

Comment: Why do you need the SRID for `shp2pgsql`? Does `shp2pgsql` not find the coordinate system from the shapefile itself?

Comment: I would be interested to know the answer to that question myself as well. By looking at the docs / examples it seems the SRID is mandatory, otherwise the polygons projections stored in Postgres could have distortion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-json` flag for `ogrinfo` is new in version 3.7 released 11 May 2023 so may not be available if you're not running the latest version.

If you have GDAL >= 3.7 and `jq` installed then you could do something like

```
# Get the full WKT 
# **Note full WKT can be more useful than SRID as not all datasets
# will have an SRID (e.g EPSG Code or ESRI SRID, etc)
ogrinfo -so -json input.shp | jq '..|objects|.wkt//empty'

# Extract Authority and Code from the projjson
ogrinfo -so -json input.shp | jq '..|objects|.projjson.id//empty'
```

E.g. using some data in WGS84 and Albers:

```
ogrinfo -so -json input_4326.shp | jq '..|objects|.wkt//empty' 
GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"latitude\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"longitude\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"

ogrinfo -so -json input_wgs84.shp | jq '..|objects|.projjson.id//empty'
{
  "authority": "EPSG",
  "code": 4326
}

ogrinfo -so -json input_albers.shp | jq '..|objects|.projjson.id//empty'
{
  "authority": "EPSG",
  "code": 3577
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON is machine readable, so run ogrinfo with the `-json` option.

```
ogrinfo sample.shp -json
{
  "description":"sample.shp",
  "driverShortName":"ESRI Shapefile",
  "driverLongName":"ESRI Shapefile",
  "layers":[
    {
      "name":"sample",
      "metadata":{
        "":{
          "DBF_DATE_LAST_UPDATE":"2023-01-04"
        },
        "SHAPEFILE":{
          "CPG_VALUE":"UTF-8",
          "ENCODING_FROM_CPG":"UTF-8",
          "SOURCE_ENCODING":"UTF-8"
        }
      },
      "geometryFields":[
        {
          "name":"",
          "type":"LineString",
          "nullable":true,
          "extent":[
            470310.57160474337,
            5773274.8877957221,
            470631.38256184058,
            5773852.4206563383
          ],
          "coordinateSystem":{
            "wkt":"PROJCRS[\"ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"ETRS89\",\n        DATUM[\"European Terrestrial Reference System 1989\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"GRS 1980\",6378137,298.257222101,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",4258]],\n    CONVERSION[\"UTM zone 32N\",\n        METHOD[\"Transverse Mercator\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9807]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of natural origin\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8801]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of natural origin\",9,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8802]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Scale factor at natural origin\",0.9996,\n            SCALEUNIT[\"unity\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8805]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False easting\",500000,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8806]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False northing\",0,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8807]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"(E)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        AXIS[\"(N)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Engineering survey, topographic mapping.\"],\n        AREA[\"Europe between 6┬░E and 12┬░E: Austria; Belgium; Denmark - onshore and offshore; Germany - onshore and offshore; Norway including - onshore and offshore; Spain - offshore.\"],\n        BBOX[38.76,6,83.92,12]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",25832]]",
            "projjson":{
              "$schema":"https://proj.org/schemas/v0.2/projjson.schema.json",
              "type":"ProjectedCRS",
              "name":"ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N",
              "base_crs":{
                "name":"ETRS89",
                "datum":{
                  "type":"GeodeticReferenceFrame",
                  "name":"European Terrestrial Reference System 1989",
                  "ellipsoid":{
                    "name":"GRS 1980",
                    "semi_major_axis":6378137,
                    "inverse_flattening":298.257222101
                  }
                },
                "coordinate_system":{
                  "subtype":"ellipsoidal",
                  "axis":[
                    {
                      "name":"Geodetic latitude",
                      "abbreviation":"Lat",
                      "direction":"north",
                      "unit":"degree"
                    },
                    {
                      "name":"Geodetic longitude",
                      "abbreviation":"Lon",
                      "direction":"east",
                      "unit":"degree"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "id":{
                  "authority":"EPSG",
                  "code":4258
                }
              },
              "conversion":{
                "name":"UTM zone 32N",
                "method":{
                  "name":"Transverse Mercator",
                  "id":{
                    "authority":"EPSG",
                    "code":9807
                  }
                },
                "parameters":[
                  {
                    "name":"Latitude of natural origin",
                    "value":0,
                    "unit":"degree",
                    "id":{
                      "authority":"EPSG",
                      "code":8801
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "name":"Longitude of natural origin",
                    "value":9,
                    "unit":"degree",
                    "id":{
                      "authority":"EPSG",
                      "code":8802
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "name":"Scale factor at natural origin",
                    "value":0.9996,
                    "unit":"unity",
                    "id":{
                      "authority":"EPSG",
                      "code":8805
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "name":"False easting",
                    "value":500000,
                    "unit":"metre",
                    "id":{
                      "authority":"EPSG",
                      "code":8806
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "name":"False northing",
                    "value":0,
                    "unit":"metre",
                    "id":{
                      "authority":"EPSG",
                      "code":8807
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
              "coordinate_system":{
                "subtype":"Cartesian",
                "axis":[
                  {
                    "name":"Easting",
                    "abbreviation":"E",
                    "direction":"east",
                    "unit":"metre"
                  },
                  {
                    "name":"Northing",
                    "abbreviation":"N",
                    "direction":"north",
                    "unit":"metre"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "scope":"Engineering survey, topographic mapping.",
              "area":"Europe between 6┬░E and 12┬░E: Austria; Belgium; Denmark - onshore and offshore; Germany - onshore and offshore; Norway including - onshore and offshore; Spain - offshore.",
              "bbox":{
                "south_latitude":38.76,
                "west_longitude":6,
                "north_latitude":83.92,
                "east_longitude":12
              },
              "id":{
                "authority":"EPSG",
                "code":25832
              }
            },
            "dataAxisToSRSAxisMapping":[
              1,
              2
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "featureCount":2212,
      "fields":[
        {
          "name":"FID",
          "type":"Integer64",
          "width":11,
          "nullable":true,
          "uniqueConstraint":false
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "metadata":{
  },
  "domains":{
  }
}
```

Comment: `-json` is new in version 3.7 released 11 May 2023.